# Jar file not running from MSSQL stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi All  I'm trying to run a jar a file from MSSQL stored procedure. But I'm getting the error "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
I'm using the following command from stored procedure

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'java -jar C:\admin\yyyyy\xxxx.jar'
```

I have installed JRE and also added it in environment variables. I'm able to execute the same jar file from command prompt. Please let me know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including the full path to the java executable (ie: c:\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar C:\admin\yyyyy\xxxx.jar)?