# send call from SQL to c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Can anyone suggest how to call a c# routine from a SQL server database? Thanks

I have a SQL Server database and each time a record is inserted through an MS Access front end, I want it to call a C# routine on a web server to email users who have subscribed to each record.

Andy

Comment: Trevor Pilleys answer is technically correct - you should however note that this will cause a major performance penalty and also probably make your DB hard to maintain. I would much rather solve this at the application level rather than in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an INSERT trigger on the table and use that to invoke SQL CLR code, that allows you to execute a .NET method based upon the INSERT happening and you can even pass values from the inserted row into the .NET code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SqlDependency feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: SqlDependency implementations are complex. Providing a full implementation that addresses the poster's scenario is not practical. Are you implying that the link should have been provided in a comment, not an answer?

Comment: @RobEpstein: Most probably yes!! Of course this guide the OP, but this doesn't answer the question directly. Not a big deal I guess, unless this link goes offline

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [database trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on an insert event into your table which calls your java executable.

Here are two helpful links for calling an executable from SQL Server using T-SQL:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652649/jar-file-not-running-from-mssql-stored-procedure)
- [Link 2](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/27/sql-server-running-batch-file-using-t-sql-xp_cmdshell-bat-file/)

Comment: Except the question was about C# rather than Java.

Comment: It's a question about running an executable... doesn't matter what type of executable - that command will do what he wants.

Comment: True, but since SQL Server has built in support for calling code in CLR assemblies, using that feature in this case makes much more sense.